# How to convert text and numbers to dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text document with spending information. I want to use pandas and Python 3 to convert the text to a dataframe with two columns, without repeating row names by combining same names into one row with the respective amounts added to produce a single total.

Original "spending.txt:"

```
shaving 150  
shaving 200  
coffee 100  
food 350  
transport 60  
transport 40
```

desired output dataframe:

```
CATEGORY       TOTAL

shaving        350  
coffee         100  
food           350  
transport      100
```

Comment: use pandas documentation

Comment: you can use *readline** to read all line of your texte file. the you can use *split* to separate text and number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('spending.txt', header=None, sep='\s+')
df.columns = ['category', 'total']

df.groupby('category', as_index=False).sum()

    category  total
0     coffee    100
1       food    350
2    shaving    350
3  transport    100
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading in data

```
temp = StringIO("""  
shaving 150
shaving 200
coffee 100
food 350
transport 60
transport 40
""")

df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep='\s+', engine='python', header=None)
```

---

```
df.groupby(0).sum().reset_index().rename({0:'category',1:'total'}, axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   category  total
0     coffee    100
1       food    350
2    shaving    350
3  transport    100
```

Comment: thanks iamklaus, it worked well. I upvoted your answer, but it's not shown. It seems like I can only tick one answer unfortunately. I ticked @zipa as for a low level programmer like me is a lot easier to process

Answer (score 0):

1. Read file using read_csv
2. The apply group by

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.rename(columns={0:'category',1:'Total'},inplace=True)

final_df = df.groupby(['category'],as_index=False)['Total'].sum()
print(final_df)
```

```
     category  Total
0     coffee    100
1       food    350
2    shaving    350
3  transport    100
```

Comment: thanks tawab_shakeel, it works like a charm,  as with iamkluas, I upvoted but can't tick as I can only tick one an Zipa's seems the clearest for a low level programmer like me

Comment: No problem @JohnAiton